# How to get a vCard (.vcf file) into Android or ios contacts from website

Tags: contacts, vcf-vcard

How to add or import vcard file contacts into android and ios phone contacts app from website directly???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Typically Android and iOS will handle downloaded vcards accordingly themselves. You just have to make sure, the server delivers the correct content-type `text/vcard` for the downloaded file

Comment: please send code in php or jquery or javascript